# React app served with express and helmet cannot make API requests

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, content-security-policy, helmet.js

I am serving a react app build using express.

```
const root = path.join(__dirname, 'build/');
app.use(express.static(root));
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  if (req.method === 'GET' && req.accepts('html') && !req.is('json') && !req.path.includes('.')) {
    res.sendFile('index.html', { root });
  } else next();
});
```

Everything works as intended. However as soon as i add `helmet` (NOT react-helmet) to the express app, I get issues (styles and scripts  didn't load).
After searching several resources I was able to come up with a solution to make it work.
The below code shows the fix i did to make the styles and scripts load.

```
app.use(helmet());
app.use(helmet.contentSecurityPolicy({
  defaultSrc: [
    '\'self\'',
    'https://api.domain.tld/*',
    'https://domain.tld',
  ],
  styleSrc: [
    '\'self\'',
    '\'unsafe-inline\'',
    'https://*.googleapis.com',
    'https://api.domain.tld/*',
    'https://domain.tld',
  ],
  scriptSrc: [
    '\'self\'',
    '\'unsafe-inline\'',
    'https://api.domain.tld/*',
    'https://domain.tld',
  ],
  contentSrc: [
    '\'self\'',
    '\'unsafe-inline\'',
    'https://api.domain.tld/*',
    'https://domain.tld',
  ],
}));
```

Additionally I also included `INLINE_RUNTIME_CHUNK=false` in the `.env file`.

The issue I have currently is that the API calls I am making to `api.domain.tld` does not work. It gets blocked and the following errors show up on firefox.

> Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at https://api.domain.tld/endpoint (“default-src”).

Chrome shows the following error.

> Refused to connect to 'https://api.domain.tld/endpoint' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Note that 'connect-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

- Please note that the react app is on `domain.tld` and the API is on `api.domain.tld`

How can if fix this issue so I can make API calls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Documentation](https://helmetjs.github.io/), You should specify sources inside the `directives`

```js
app.use(helmet.contentSecurityPolicy({
  useDefaults: false, // you can change it to `true` if you want.
  directives:{
    defaultSrc: [
      '\'self\'',
      'https://api.domain.tld/',
      'https://domain.tld',
    ],
    styleSrc: [
      '\'self\'',
      '\'unsafe-inline\'',
      'https://*.googleapis.com',
      'https://api.domain.tld/',
      'https://domain.tld',
    ],
    'image-src': [
      '\'self\'',
      '\'unsafe-inline\'',
      'data:',
      'https://api.domain.tld/',
      'https://domain.tld',
    ],
    scriptSrc: [
      '\'self\'',
      '\'unsafe-inline\'',
      'https://api.domain.tld/*',
      'https://domain.tld',
    ],
    contentSrc: [
      '\'self\'',
      '\'unsafe-inline\'',
      'https://api.domain.tld/',
      'https://domain.tld',
    ],
  }
}));
```

**Update**

To fix the image not loading issue, Add the following.

```
   imageSrc: [
      '\'self\'',
      '\'unsafe-inline\'',
      'data:',
      'https://api.domain.tld/',
      'https://domain.tld',
   ],
```

Comment: Hi this works. There was one issue where the images were not loading. I fixed it in your code by adding 'image-src'.

Answer (score 1):

There is 2 issues:

1. Do fix a syntax error: `contentSrc:` -> `connectSrc:`
2. CSP spec does not allow using * (wildcard) in the path-part, therefore do fix  `'https://api.domain.tld/*` -> `'https://api.domain.tld/'`. Also in the path-part you can use:

- a folder name: `'https://api.domain.tld/real_path_here/'` (with trailing slash **/**) - will allow any subfolders and any files in specified folder and subs.
- file name: `'https://api.domain.tld/endpoint'` or `'https://api.domain.tld/some_path/script.js'` (without trailing slash **/**) - will allow specified file_name only.